# Is there a way to fetch associative array grouped by the values of a two colums with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I executed this query

```
 $sql = "
 SELECT cls
     , sctn
     , COUNT(case when gender='M' then 1 end) boys
     , COUNT(case when gender='F' then 1 end) girls
   FROM student_table
  WHERE active = 1 
  group 
     by cls
     , sctn";


 $stmt->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then I got this result

```
 Array
    (
      [1st] => Array(
            [0] => Array (
                    [sctn] => A
                    [boys] => 8
                    [girls] => 7
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [sctn] => B
                    [boys] => 5
                    [girls] => 4
                )
        )
     [2nd] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [sctn] => A
                    [boys] => 3
                    [girls] => 7
                )
            [1] => Array  (
                    [sctn] => B
                    [boys] => 8
                    [girls] => 5
                )
        )
     [3rd] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [sctn] => A
                    [boys] => 9
                    [girls] => 11
                )
            [1] => Array  (
                    [sctn] => B
                    [boys] => 5
                    [girls] => 17
                )
        )
    )
```

but the  result that I am expecting is

```
Array
(
  [1st] => Array(
        [A] => Array (
                [boys] => 8
                [girls] => 7
            )
        [B] => Array (
               [boys] => 5
                [girls] => 4
            )
    )
 [2nd] => Array (
        [A] => Array (
                [boys] => 3
                [girls] => 7
            )
        [B] => Array  (
                [boys] => 8
                [girls] => 5
            )
    )
 [3rd] => Array (
        [A] => Array (
               [boys] => 9
                [girls] => 11
            )
        [B] => Array  (
                [boys] => 5
                [girls] => 17
            )
    )
)
```

Here I would like to count class wise and section wise and gender wise

I need sctn value also as a key to the nested array

Is there any way to get this result according to my `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` can work with multiple groups like this.

I think you'll just have to fetch it one row at a time into the structure you want instead of using `fetchAll`.

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array[$row['cls']][$row['sctn']]['boys'] = $row['boys'];
    $array[$row['cls']][$row['sctn']]['girls'] = $row['girls'];
}
```